# How would I go about dynamically changing a text area based on the option chosen?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, textarea

So basically what I'm trying to do is create a template email form to send.
A user can choose from the options of which predefined template that already exist in either a html file or mysql database.

Once the user chooses from the option then the text will autoload into the text area already good to go.

I'm using PHP, Jquery, Javascript to build this out.

I'm looking into a few MC Editors and haven't decided whether the html will be held in files or the mysql database.

Pretty new at this. Where do I start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change()` functions can be used to see when a `select` has been changed. You can then check the value of the chosen option and do what you need to do. Quick example:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

And your jQuery:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "1") {
        console.log("User picked the first option");
        $("textarea").val("User picked option one!"); //Adds content to a textarea

        //make some ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: "/call/",
            ...
            ...
            success: function() {
                //successful!
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This should be a good starting point to do what you need.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I wanted on my front end. So the next question I would have is how, when user makes the selection, do I pull the data from mysql and load it into the textarea?

Comment: AJAX my friend, plenty of tutorials on it :)

Comment: Quick heads up, be sure to have your console open when you're debugging AJAX calls, can save a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/rtP9c/8/

See if that helps

```
<div id="email">
To <div class="template name">2</div><br/>

I am Jack's email template. I am a unique and beautiful <div class="template insect"></div>. Did you know that you are not your <div class="template possession"></div>.<br>

From <div class="template from"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var email = {
    name : 'Tyler', 
    insect : 'butterfly', 
    possession : 'Khaki Pants', 
    from : 'Narrator'
};

$('.template').each(function(k,v){
   var template = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    $(this).text(email[template]);
});
```

Or through AJAX:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://site.com'
      dataType: 'json',
      data : data,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.template').each(function(k,v){
            var template = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
            $(this).text(data[template]);
        });        
      },
      error: function(status) {
        console.log(status);
      }
    });
```